# Java TCP Socket Programming: Can not connect to remote host

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a java program which accepts a http request from web browser and in response, program sends a text file contents to display in web browser. The program is working fine when I make request from browser which is installed on the same machine in which java code is running but when I make request from some other web browser which is not on the same machine as in which java code running, the program does not get any request.

This is how I make request from my web browser:-

```
http://localhost:port_number/   
This is working fine...
```

This is how I make request from some other web browser which is not on my machine:

```
http://my_ip_address:port_number/
This is not working...
```

And this is my java code:-

```
while (true) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(32768);
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            InetAddress ia = clientSocket.getInetAddress();
            jTextArea1.append("Connected to : " + ia + "\n");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            String inputLine, outputLine;
            String s = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter File Name : ");
            File f = new File(s);
            if (f.exists()) {
                out.println("http/1.1 200 ok\r");
                out.println("Mime version 1.1");
                out.println("Content-Type: text/html\r");
                out.println("Content-Length: " + f.length() + "\r");
                out.println("\r");
                BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));
                String line = " ", a;
                while ((a = d.readLine()) != null) {
                    line = line + a;
                }
                out.write(line);
                out.flush();
                jTextArea1.append("File Delivered.\n");
                d.close();
            }
            out.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            jTextArea1.append("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This smells like a networking issue ... firewall, routing

Comment: I dont think so...I know I am doing something wrong somewhere but dont know- where

Comment: Try using another client like telnet: `telnet 1.2.3.4:32768 80` type `GET /`+[enter] and tell us the error you get.

Comment: Also put a debug-print statement aftet the call to `accept()`.

Comment: Define 'not working'. What happens instead? What does the browser show? NB You're not sending valid HTTP. The line terminator in HTTP headers is \r\n, not just \r. You're missing a line terminator altogether on the MIME header, and a colon as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the code that you've written. You need to make your IP address publicly accessible. [Here's](https://superuser.com/questions/526899/how-to-make-my-ip-publicly-accessible-to-make-my-local-tomcat-server-public) is a related thread.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check that you are indeed listening on 0.0.0.0:32768 and not 127.0.0.1:32768 or any other particulat IP (specially if you are connected to several network). Start a shell and use netstat -ano on Windows and netstat -anp on Unix or Mac.
2. Check that your firewall allows remote connection to the port 32768

Comment: new ServerSocket(32768) does not listen at 127.0.0.1 or any other particular IP address, it listens at 0.0.0.0.

Comment: This is not said anywhere in the Javadoc. Plus, if you set up a custom `ServerSocketFactory`, you have not guarantee that `new ServerSocket(32768)` will listen on 0.0.0.0

Comment: (1) Nevertheless it is true. (2) If you call `new ServerSocket`, no `ServerSocketFactory` is involved.

Comment: 1°) Please support with official documentation 2°) `ServerSocket.setSocketFactory` will set the default factory for the whole application without having to explicitly called the factory

Comment: (1) ***I*** don't have to support it with official documentation. It's your assertion that it can be other than `0.0.0.0` with this code: *you* support it. You can't. There isn't any. It's the default. If you want something other than `INADDR_ANY` you specify a bind-address. Have a look at the API. Try it before you post again. (2) You mentioned `ServerSocketFactory.` There's one in `javax.net,` which has nothing to do with `ServerSocket.setSocketFactory(),` which you now mention, and which doesn't take an argument of type `ServerSocketFactory,` and which there is no evidence of in this post.

Comment: 1°) Yes, I support that it might be different than 0.0.0.0 because I could not find any doc saying it would always be 0.0.0.0, as you repeatedly asserted. Result obtained by running piece of code on your machine cannot be used to validate global behavior 2°) `ServerSocket.setSocketFactory` will change the default impl for all `ServerSocket` in the application. Have a look at the API as well. And yes, there is no evidence of custom socket here but since we are not provided with the whole code, there is nothing wrong assuming. This is why the test I proposed covered a lot of possibilities.